# Implement Oauth between own server and iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, ios9

I want to secure my http calls between the mobile app and my own server.
What is the best approach to do this ? I was seeing oAuth2.0 but not able to understand it completely. How we can use tokenised authentication in our app ? Could someone help me out in this by explaining with example for both sides (iOS and Server). I don't want user to switch to safari when authenticating like we do when we tap on sign-in with google+ and it switches to a web page etc.

Comment: If you just want to authenticate your app and not individual users you can use an HMAC

Comment: I want something like we send authorisation header and the value should be an valid access token with session timeout. Something like amazon AWS but on my own server

Comment: So you are authenticating the individual users of your app?

Comment: not user's I want to authenticating http calls

Comment: That is what I want to understand - If you just want to know that it is your app sending the request and not some other app then you don't need OAuth.  If you want to authenticate that it is a specific user then maybe you need OAuth.   OAuth is a trust model of authentication where the relying party (your server) is separate from the trusted party (the service who authenticates the user).  It is like a drivers license.  One party issues the license and another party (say the police) trust that identification when you show it.

Comment: I want authenticated users to use the app.I mean only authenticated should be able to make another api calls throughout the app by using some access token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98893/discussion-between-rahul-vyas-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I dont know how to set this on server.
But You can pass auth username and password from application side like this.

```
NSMutableString *loginString = (NSMutableString*)[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:%@", AuthUserName, AuthPassword];
NSData *authData  = [loginString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authHeader    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];

NSString *urlString = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                timeoutInterval:DEFAULT_TIMEOUT];

[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: this is old way I guess we should use NSURLSession class

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would help you to get started, it is a clear cut implementation of Oauth 2.0 with Swift,

http://www.raywenderlich.com/99431/oauth-2-with-swift-tutorial

using Google services as the OAuth Provider (free of cost)

Other libraries that provide integration with already built Oauth services,

https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-ios - This is the iOS SDK for OAuth.io. OAuth.io allows you to integrate 100+ providers really easily in your web app, without worrying about each provider's OAuth specific implementation.

https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client - It implements the native application profile and supports the end-user authorization endpoint via an internal or an external user-agent. Furthermore it also supports the user credentials flow by prompting the end-user for their username and password and use them directly to obtain an access token.

Comment: I guess it will open a web page to provide access token I do not want that flow

Comment: OAuth2Client has the ability to switch between browser based user authentication and credential based Oauth Token authorization. Check that lib.